# How to count negative number in an array?

Tags: java

In a hacker rank problem, i want to count the number of negative numbers. if the count is greater than an integer k, then I must print no. Else yes. I get runtime error. Is there any way to count faster?

my code goes

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();

        for (int l = 0; l < t; l++) {
            int count = 0;
            int k = s.nextInt();
            int n = s.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> al  =new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                al.add(s.nextInt());
            }

            Collections.sort(al);

            for (int c : al) {
                if (c <= 0) {
                    count += 1;
                } else
                    break;
            }

            if ((count >= k) || (count == k)) {
                System.out.println("NO");
            } else {
                System.out.println("YES");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: you should write correct code first, then think about optimization.

Comment: If your code is really working completely correctly, and you just want some pointers on how to make it faster, then consider moving this question to our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The purpose of using `>=` is to not have to compare with `==` aswell.
Just use `if(count>=k)` instead of `if((count>=k)||(count==k))`

Comment: runtime error... just runtime error..

Comment: You shouldn’t be writing ‘count==k’! Secondly, it should be ‘c<0’

Comment: stii no change christoffer. same runtime error

Comment: downvoted due to unclear question: what is the error, where it happens, what did you try to do to solve it. hint: errors have stacktrace. Will remove once you fix the issue

Comment: *I get runtime error* what is it?

Comment: By sorting, you made an O(n log n) algorithm for a problem that is easily solved in O(n).

Comment: time consumption. the error is time consumption

Answer (score 2):

Sorting `ArrayList<Integer>` is O(n log n). Doing a single pass over the `ArrayList` with a counter is O(n). Don't sort, don't store additional temporary variables, exit the moment you reach the `k` if you can stop reading input with `Scanner`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (s.nextInt() < 0) {
    counter++;
  } 
  if (counter > k) {
    System.out.println("NO");
    return;
  }
}
System.out.println("YES");
```

Comment: This is the only optimised solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your list and check if the current number is smaller than zero, so you will have a negative number. Every time this fact is true, increment your count. Simple and easy! This is also not slow and the normal way to deal with this. If you might have trillions of numbers and you also know the exact size of the Collection, you can divide the collection in separate sections (Keyword 'Divide and Conquer'). Then do this iteration for each section in an own thread.

KISS - Keep it simple stupid

```
int count = 0;
Collection <Integer> s = null;
for(Integer i : s) {
    if(i < 0)
        count++;
    if(count > k)
        System.exit(-1);

}
```